# How to open a particular link in a new tab in selenium/python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a link in a new tab,that particular link is present in webpage. All the examples i have seen online seems to send the link directly in code and open that link in a new tab rather than getting it dynamically

Changerequest is the link i want open in a new tab and closing the new tab after doing some function

```
Sourcecontrol = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a[contains(.,"Source Control")]')
   Sourcecontrol.click();
   Changerequest=driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//td[@class="confluenceTd"]/a[contains(.,"Change: ")]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't');
   #testvalue = Changerequest.get_attribute('href')
   driver.execute_script("window.open(Changerequest)")
```

When i use the short cut  keys nothing seems to happen

```
send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Comment: CTRL+T opens a new blank tab, it won't open a specific URL in that tab. You could open the new tab and then set the desired URL. You might try SHIFT+clicking the link as I think that might work in some browsers but I haven't tried it myself and it may depend on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
Sourcecontrol = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a[contains(.,"Source Control")]')
Sourcecontrol.click();
Changerequest=driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//td[@class="confluenceTd"]/a[contains(.,"Change: ")]')
testvalue = Changerequest.get_attribute('href')
driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])",testvalue)
```